# Creating Histogram from Poisson Distributions with weights (matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, poisson

I am working on a project looking at the Poisson filling of droplets by a contaminant whereby the Poisson mean depends on the droplets Volume. There is a volume distribution and each volume size has a likelihood from a Gaussian.

I have a loop generating a Poisson distribution (an array of 2000 numbers) for a different mean in each step. Each distribution has a weight that I generate from a gaussian. Currently, I am just adding all Poisson arrays and creating one large normalised histogram. I wish to weight the frequency of numbers in each array, such that the histogram can take into account the weight. I am unsure how to do this however as it is the frequency of the numbers in each array that has to be weighted and not the numbers themselves.

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.stats import poison
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def gaussian(mu,sig,x):  # Gaussian Gives Weight
    
  P_r = 1./(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*sig)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig, 2.)/2)

  return P_r

def poisson(mean):
  P = np.random.poisson(mean, 2000)
  return P

R= np.linspace(45, 75, 2000) #min and max radius and steps taken between them to gen Poisson

Average_Droplet_Radius = 60
Variance = 15
Mean_Droplet_Average_Occupancy = float(input('Enter mean droplet occupation ')) #Poisson Mean

for mu, sig in [(Average_Droplet_Radius,Variance)]:
    np.prob = gaussian(mu,sig,R)


C = Mean_Droplet_Average_Occupancy / (4/3 *np.pi * ( Average_Droplet_Radius**3)) #The constant parameter for all distributions


i = 0
a = np.array([])

for cell in R:   

    Individual_Mean = C * (4/3 *np.pi * ( R[i]**3))

    Individual_Weight = np.prob[i] #want to weight frequency in given Poisson by this

    b = (poisson(Individual_Mean))
    a = np.append(a, b) # Unweighted Poissons combined
    i = i+1


bins_val = np.arange(0, a.max() + 1.5) - 0.5
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist( a, bins_val, density=True)    # Creates unweighted, normalised histogram 


plt.show()
```

I was unsure how to use the weights part of plt.hist, as it is a large array of numbers that has weight.
Currently, I get a histogram where each droplet size is equally likely, how can I get the weights in the final distribution?

Comment: Maybe you could use a loop (or the Counter module) to count the frequency of the numbers manually, and create a list of frequencies that way? From there you can put that list as the weights of plt.hist. I'm not very familiar with the use of weights but the official docs have more info. Hope this helped!